# Loading collection view with task async method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to load thumbnails with async task method with depency service :

In my pcl page I have this :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading...", MaskType.Black));

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                directoryPath = await getThumbnails.GetBitmaps(fileInfo.FullName);
                List<ThumbnailsModel> thumbnailsModels = new List<ThumbnailsModel>();

                int i = 1;
                Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).ToList<string>().ForEach(delegate (string thumbnailsEmplacement)
                {
                    thumbnailsModels.Add(new ThumbnailsModel(i, thumbnailsEmplacement));
                    i++;
                });
                CollectionViewThumbnails.ItemsSource = thumbnailsModels;


            }).ContinueWith(result => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {


                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            }
        )
        );
        }
```

My method to get the thumbnails :

```
public async Task<string> GetBitmaps(string filePath)
    {

        //TODO-- WORK ON THIS

        var appDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDirectory, "thumbnailsTemp", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));

        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        using (Stream resourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            resourceStream.CopyTo(stream);
        }

        Document document = new Document(stream);
        int count = document.Pages.Count;

        for(int i = 0; i<= count; i++) {
            TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.Page page = document.Pages[0];

            using (var outputStream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName + "Thumbnails" + i + ".png"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {

                await Task.Run(() =>
                {

                    page.SaveAsBitmap(outputStream, CompressFormat.Png, 5);
                });
            }
        }

        return directoryPath;
    }
```

The problem is that my application is going in my Dependency service method then going back in my pcl OnAppearing method before the thumbnails are done and going at this line

> UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();

Comment: Not sure what your problem is because I don't program in xamarin but what I do know is that if you want to program async you also need to add [ConfigureAwait()](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) also you got a memory leak because your memory stream also has a dispose pattern so you need to use a using for that as well.

Comment: Short answer: Don't use `ContinueWith`; use `await` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have an unhandled exception.  That continuation *will run* even if an exception is thrown on the `Task` you're continuing.

This can be changed using something like `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompleted` (and [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions?view=netframework-4.8)) in the overload for `ContinueWith`.  The default is `TaskContinuationOptions.None` if not specified.

Alternatively, you can access `result.Exception` in your continuation if you want it to run on failure and handle it.

Comment: Well, now the process is working perfectly. I have all my items in my list but when I am hiding the loading page not a single item on my screen.

Comment: Correctly said and well explained

Comment: Ok Fixed issue, I set the item source of my collection view just before hiding the loading page. It work, ty.